# Некорректно работает библиотека FullCalendar.js в Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint

Работаем в SharePoint Designer 2013, были подключены все необходимые для работы с данной библиотекой файлы:

```
-fullcalendar.min.css
-jquery-ui.min.css
-jquery.SPServices-2014.02.min.js
-moment.js
-fullcalendar.js
-locale-all.js
и js-файл инициализации (The Full Code), взятый со странички (https://joshmccarty.com/2011/11/sharepoint-jquery-and-fullcalendar-now-with-spservices/)
```

При открытии страницы с календарем открывается только его верхняя часть с кнопками управления визуализацией (день, месяц, неделя, privious, next).
Кликнув по кнопке privious либо next - календарь разворачивается в полный вид, как и должен работать изначально.
Так же на каждый клик в консоль возвращается ошибка:

`Uncaught TypeError: $.fullCalendar.formatDate is not a function
    at Calendar_constructor.events (fullcodecalendar.js:84)
    at _fetchEventSource (fullcalendar.js:11692)
    at tryFetchEventSource (fullcalendar.js:11602)
    at fetchEventSources (fullcalendar.js:11585)
    at refetchEvents (fullcalendar.js:11549)
    at fetchEvents (fullcalendar.js:11543)
    at Calendar_constructor.requestEvents (fullcalendar.js:11485)
    at members.constructor.requestEvents (fullcalendar.js:9061)
    at members.constructor.bindEvents (fullcalendar.js:8866)
    at fullcalendar.js:8436`
Предполагаю, что ответ лежит где-то на поверхности, но отловить пока не получается.
Если кто-то сталкивался с похожей проблемой или мб имел необходимость подключения данной библиотеки к системе на SharePoint - буду очень благодарен за обратную связь!
Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Подскажите, какую версию `fullcalendar.js` вы используете. Метод `formatDate` был доступен до v2.0. Ознакомиться со списком изменений можно ознакомиться [тут](https://fullcalendar.io/wiki/Upgrading-to-v2/).

Т.е. вместо

```
$.fullCalendar.formatDate(date, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
```

необходимо использовать

```
moment(date, 'DD.MM.YYYY').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
```

где `DD.MM.YYYY` - текущий формат даты, а `format('YYYY-MM-DD')` задает целевой формат даты.